# Up and Down Enemy Movement using translate corona sdk

Tags: android, lua, coronasdk

i want my bird to have a up and down movement when it plays here is my code

```
function updateMons2()
      for a = 1, mons2.numChildren, 1 do
        physics.addBody(mons2[a],"kinematic")
          if(mons2[a].isAlive == true) then
              (mons2[a]):translate(speed * -1, 0)            

              if(mons2[a].x < -80) then
                  mons2[a].x = 1000
                  mons2[a].y = 500
                  mons2[a].isAlive = false 
              end
          end
      end
  end
```

this code only does is from right to left i want my bird to move up and down while it is going left can someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a sample. try this:

```
local mons2 = {}
local yPos = {}
for i=1,2 do
  mons2[i] = display.newImageRect("1.png",50,50)
  mons2[i].x = 100
  mons2[i].y = 100+(100*(i-1))
  mons2[i].isAlive = true
  yPos[i] = mons2[i].y
end

speed = 10
count_ = 0
function updateMons2()
  count_ = count_ + 1
  for a = 1, 2, 1 do
    physics.addBody(mons2[a],"kinematic")
     if(mons2[a].isAlive == true) then
       mons2[a]:translate(speed * -1, 0)
       transition.to(mons2[a],{time=50,y=yPos[a]+(20*(count_%2)*-1)})
         if(mons2[a].x < -80) then
           mons2[a].x = 350
         end
     end
  end
end
timer.performWithDelay(100,updateMons2,-1)
```

Keep Coding........... :)

Comment: my if condition there is if the monster reaches -80 it will return  back to its position x=1000 y=500 and the translate you did only does is change the y downwards and not moving to the left what i need is the monster moving to the left while moving up and down thanks for trying to help anyways

Comment: I've edited the code. Check whether it satisfies your need/not... :)